# Replace Ember's if helper

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember 1.0, in which the `if` helper treats empty arrays as falsy. 
I would like to replace it with a more native JS one, such that:

`false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined` - will return `false`;
all the rest, including `[]`, `{}`, `function() {}`, will be truthy.

How do I do that and register the new helper using `registerBoundHelper`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hidden feature in the `if` helper. If you provide a `isTruthy` property in the object, it will be used. So using `Array.prototype.isTruthy = true;` will make all arrays be evaluated like true, without create any helper.

Give a look in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/yb6LR/ to see this working.

Comment: Nice!
Though it still a little problematic when you have other parts in the code that rely on [] being !isTruthy.
Doing it selectively somehow, using another helper rather than overriding the default behaviour is safer.

Comment: Isn't possible at the moment to override the default `if` view helper, not without hardcode some internal ember functions. So I think that you will need to use this globally.

Answer (score 0):

Ember doesn't currently support custom block helpers, so without editing the source code, there might not be a way. Depending on where you need to use this, you could always created a custom computed property.

Comment: I need it across all the app, so I wouldn't mind using registerHelper rather than registerBoundHelper to overcome the problem.
Is it possible to bind the property somehow in that alternative implementation?